# Accessing url arguments through request args in flask

Tags: flask

I had been trying to deploy a machine learning model through flask. I need to pass some text through url so that it could be retrieved for classification. I am using request.args.get function but its throwing the error:

```
TypeError: index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

The url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/text=Windows%20is%20a%20operating%20system
```

Its showing the error too:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

service.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

file = open("models/GridSearchCV_nb.pickle","rb")
nb_clf = pickle.load(file)

file = open("models/GridSearchCV_svm.pickle","rb")
svc_clf = pickle.load(file)

file = open("models/ctargets.pickle","rb")
targets = pickle.load(file)

def nbclassifyit(text):
  idx_nb = nb_clf.predict([text])[0]
  return targets[idx_nb]

def svclassifyit(text):
  idx_svc = svc_clf.predict([text])[0]
  return targets[idx_svc]


@app.route('/index/<text>')
def index():
 text = request.args.get('text')
 result = {"prediction" : nbclassifyit(text)}
 return jsonify(result)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.args.get` function looks for arguments after a `?` at the end of the route. You don't need to use `<text>` in your route.

So you can try changing your index route and function like this:

```
@app.route('/index/')
def index():
 text = request.args.get('text')
 result = {"prediction" : nbclassifyit(text)}
 return jsonify(result)
```

And giving the text argument in your url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/?text=Windows%20is%20a%20operating%20system
```

Comment: You could remove the last `/` from the path. And the url is going to be: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/index?text=Windows%20is%20a%20operating%20system`

Comment: Yeah you could, I think the `/` is optional, the route will work with both patterns right?